# Dart get the current weekday using DateTime object

Tags: dart

I want to get the current weekday in dart. But I do not know how. Please help?
I need to use the DateTime object I guess

```
DateTime
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use DateTime.now().weekday
That will give you an int of 1-7 representing the current weekday

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the values follow the ISO 8601 standard, which means that a week starts on Monday (1) and ends on Sunday (7). [Here's a link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html) to the documentation.